# Semi-transparent highlights using PySide and QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyside, alphablending, qtextedit

I've created a QTextEdit object. The code below adds randomly colored highlights to the currently selected text. I need the highlights to be semi-transparent so I can see highlights layered upon each other. Using "setAlpha" does not appear to do anything. How can I set the alpha for the highlight or otherwise obtain semi-transparency?

```
# Define cursor & span    
self.cursor = self.textdoc.textCursor()
self.selstart = self.cursor.selectionStart()
self.selend = self.cursor.selectionEnd()
self.seltext = self.cursor.selectedText()

# Create random color
r = randint(0,255)
g = randint(0, 255)
b = randint(0, 255)
color = QColor(r,g,b)
color.setAlpha(125)
format = QTextCharFormat()
format.setBackground(color)
self.cursor.setCharFormat(format)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems unlikely that `QTextEdit` would support anything as sophisticated as layered formatting. So I think you will have to do the blending of colours yourself. The example below uses a fairly crude method, but it seems to work okay. I'm not exactly sure what results you're aiming for, but it should give you some idea how to proceeed:

```
import sys
from random import sample
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Highlight', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.edit.setText(open(__file__).read())
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def blendColors(self, first, second, ratio=0.5, alpha=100):
        ratio2 = 1 - ratio
        return QtGui.QColor(
            (first.red() * ratio) + (second.red() * ratio2),
            (first.green() * ratio) + (second.green() * ratio2),
            (first.blue() * ratio) + (second.blue() * ratio2),
            alpha,
            )

    def handleButton(self):
        cursor = self.edit.textCursor()
        start = cursor.selectionStart()
        end = cursor.selectionEnd()
        if start != end:
            default = QtGui.QTextCharFormat().background().color()
            color = QtGui.QColor(*sample(range(0, 255), 3))
            color.setAlpha(100)
            for pos in range(start, end):
                cursor.setPosition(pos)
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCharacter,
                                    QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                charfmt = cursor.charFormat()
                current = charfmt.background().color()
                if current != default:
                    charfmt.setBackground(self.blendColors(current, color))
                else:
                    charfmt.setBackground(color)
                cursor.setCharFormat(charfmt)
            cursor.clearSelection()
            self.edit.setTextCursor(cursor)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 100, 600, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(PS: one thing I haven't attempted to implement here is *removing* highlights. If you used a relatively small set of colours, I suppose you could pre-compute a table of all colour combinations, and then use a key of `(current_color, removed_color)` to look up the required "subtracted" colour).

Comment: thank you. Your code solves the display issue. I'm worried about the complexity of adding and removing highlights though. Alpha in the textEdit implies some sort of layering, correct? What can be layered? Is there a Qt widget besides textEdit that might provide the layering of highlights specifically?

Comment: A look-up table is about as simple and efficient as it gets. There is no layering; there's only background painting. I suppose the graphics framework offers more possibilities, but it seems a heavyweight solution for something as basic as this.

Comment: I've continued to try to get alpha to work. In the QTextEdit window, setAlpha appears to function more like a saturation setting than true transparency. Your answer seems like the only show in town. Thank you.

Comment: What is `color = QtGui.QColor(*sample(range(0, 255), 3))` doing exactly? Is it creating a 255x3 look up table? I would expect to need a lookup table with 3 dimensions for R,G,B and then another dimension for the length of the text file being highlighted.

Comment: I'd expect to initialize the lookup table to the default color value (white). So, I don't understand: what is the purpose of sampling?

Comment: The `sample` is just selecting a random colour (because that's what you did in your question). I assume your real application uses a fixed set of colours. My look-up table idea is much simpler than yours. But it assumes the alpha-blending will be applied in a fixed order (unlike the basic demo script shown in my answer). This is an important point, because if you allow **all** permutations, the number of colour blends quickly becomes very unwieldy. For a set of 3 colours, it works out to 16 blends (i.e. the powerset of permutations); 4 = 65; 5 = 326; 6 = 1957; 7 = 13700.

Comment: What is the "*" before "sample" doing? Is that prefix notation for multiplication or is it necessary grammatically to define a lookup table? I'm new to Python syntax and predominantly have been using lists. Doesn't "range" produce a list?

Comment: But if the colours are blended in fixed order, you only need the powerset of *combinations*: 3 = 8; 4 = 16; 5 = 32; 6 = 64; 7 = 128. This is small enough for a hard-coded reverse look-up table of blends. So to remove a highlight, you would just get the current colour; look it up in the table to get the tuple of colours it is a blend of; remove the highlight from that tuple; then look up the resulting tuple to get the "subtracted" blend.

Comment: @davideps. There is no look-up table in my answer. As I said at the end: I did not attempt to implement any of that. The `*` syntax just expands the list produced by `sample` into the three arguments required by `QColor`. But really, this part of my answer has no relevance whatsoever to the rest. Just replace it with three `randint(0, 255)` arguments if it bothers you.

Comment: OK. Thank you for this working example. It is very helpful.

Comment: do you have time to look at my new code? Should I just create a new question for the new code?

Comment: @davideps. Yes, please always create a new question, so that everybody has a chance to see it. You can link to the previous question to provide some additional context.