# Get list of highlights under mouse in QTextEdit using PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

The code below creates a database of highlight locations and applies them to a string in a QTextEdit window. I have a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628690/semi-transparent-highlights-using-pyside-and-qtextedit) concerning semi-transparent highlights. Here, I would like suggestions about how to implement "mouse-over" functionality to return a list of the database "id" of the highlights. [QHoverEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhoverevent.html#details) does not appear to be the right tool for this job because it acts at the level of widgets so it cannot detect the highlights. Is there something I should use instead?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtSql import *

def create_database():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("highlights.sqlite")
    db.open()
    q = QSqlQuery()
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE highlights(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, start INTEGER, end INTEGER, r INTEGER, g INTEGER, b INTEGER)")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO highlights VALUES(1,0,20,100,200,100)")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO highlights VALUES(2,25,40,200,100,100)")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO highlights VALUES(3,35,50,100,100,200)")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.center = QMainWindow(self)
        self.textdoc = QTextEdit("After the creation of the application object, we have created a QLabel object. A QLabel is a widget that can present text (simple or rich, like html), and images. Note that after the creation of the label, we are calling the method show which will present the label to the user.")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textdoc)

def load_highlights():
    cursor = mainwindow.textdoc.textCursor()
    model = QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable("highlights")
    model.select()
    count = model.rowCount()
    for n in range(count):
        record = model.record(n)
        start = record.value('start')
        end = record.value('end')
        r = record.value('r')
        g = record.value('g')
        b = record.value('b')
        color = QColor(r, g, b)
        cursor.setPosition(start)
        cursor.setPosition(end, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        mainwindow.textdoc.setTextCursor(cursor)
        format = QTextCharFormat()
        format.setBackground(color)
        mainwindow.textdoc.setCurrentCharFormat(format)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_database()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    load_highlights()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()

    db.close()
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt here to write the necessary mouse handling. This makes it look like you are asking someone to write most of the code for you, which is not how things generally work on SO. What specific problems have you encountered in trying to implement the required functionality?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I'm looking for which function or method might be appropriate. I'm not looking for a complete solution--just a direction to move in. QHoverEvent does not appear to be the right way.

Comment: You need to subclass the text-edit and override [mouseMoveEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) to get the position of the mouse-cursor. There are probably hundreds of questions on SO about that. Once you have a position, you can pass it to [cursorForPosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#cursorForPosition) to get a text-cursor.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read up on how to do that and then implement it.