# Semi-transparent highlights using PySide and QTextEdit (version 2)

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtextedit

I'm trying to make a more complete example of [semi-transparent highlights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628690/semi-transparent-highlights-using-pyside-and-qtextedit/46634111?noredirect=1#comment80377090_46634111) using lists for:

(1) aggregate R,G,B,A, and highlight counts (five lists)

(2) average R,G,B,A (four lists)

The values in the average list get assigned as background colors. The aggregate lists are used to compute the average by adding and subtracting highlight colors. Each list has as many elements as characters in the text widget.

I'm using a pandas dataframe to store the highlights in memory, since there may be a ton of them to process in various ways as well as other data eventually. Placing the mouse over a character prints out its location, number of highlights, and RGBA values. Except, a problem pops up sometimes--as if a paint brush gets dragged for a second when moving from one highlight location to another. Look at the turquoise color on the "e" at the end of the text "PySide.QtCore". I think the problem is how I'm using the set and move positions of the cursor--but I'm not certain. Do I need to reset the position of the cursor after adding each highlight? Am I not selecting a single character correctly?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

def connect_database(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        return None

def create_data(connection): # database connection
    c = connection.cursor() # database cursor
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE sections(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, start INTEGER, end INTEGER, r INTEGER, g INTEGER, b INTEGER, a INTEGER)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO sections VALUES(1,0,20,100,200,100,100)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO sections VALUES(2,15,20,200,100,100,50)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO sections VALUES(3,18,30,100,100,200,100)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO sections VALUES(4,50,60,100,200,200,150)")
    db.commit()
    return c.lastrowid


class QTextEdit2(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.cursor = self.textCursor()

        self.length = len(self.toPlainText())
        self.bg_red = [0 for n in range(self.length)]    # stores aggregate values of all highlights (not averages)
        self.bg_green = [0 for n in range(self.length)]
        self.bg_blue = [0 for n in range(self.length)]
        self.bg_alpha = [0 for n in range(self.length)]
        self.bg_count = [0 for n in range(self.length)] # number of highlights. if this is 0 then don't display
                                                        # stored r,g,b just display white. in this example
                                                        # only highlights are written. everything else stays
                                                        # default

        self.display_red = [0 for n in range(self.length)]    # set to the value to display (average of highlights)
        self.display_green = [0 for n in range(self.length)]
        self.display_blue = [0 for n in range(self.length)]
        self.display_alpha = [0 for n in range(self.length)]

        self.sections = self.load_sections()
        self.color_sections()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = QPoint()
        x = event.x()
        y = event.y()
        point.setX(x)
        point.setY(y)
        n = self.cursorForPosition(point).position()
        print("%d: Section Count: %d   RGBA: %d %d %d %d" % (n, self.bg_count[n],self.display_red[n], self.display_green[n],self.display_blue[n], self.display_alpha[n]))
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


    def load_sections(self):
        c = sqlite3.connect("qda_test_01.sqlite")
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM sections", c)
        return df


    def blend_colors(self, start, end, r, g, b, a):
        for n in range(start,end):
            self.bg_red[n] = self.bg_red[n]+r
            self.bg_green[n] = self.bg_green[n]+g
            self.bg_blue[n] = self.bg_blue[n]+b
            self.bg_alpha[n] = self.bg_alpha[n]+a
            self.bg_count[n] = self.bg_count[n]+1
            self.display_red[n] = self.bg_red[n]/self.bg_count[n]
            self.display_green[n] = self.bg_green[n] / self.bg_count[n]
            self.display_blue[n] = self.bg_blue[n] / self.bg_count[n]
            self.display_alpha[n] = self.bg_alpha[n] / self.bg_count[n]
            if self.display_red[n] > 255:   # just in case RGBA data is weird...
                self.display_red[n] = 255
            if self.display_green[n] > 255:
                self.display_green[n] = 255
            if self.display_blue[n] > 255:
                self.display_blue[n] = 255
            if self.display_alpha[n] > 255:
                self.display_alpha[n] = 255
            if self.display_red[n] < 0:
                self.display_red[n] = 0
            if self.display_green[n] < 0:
                self.display_green[n] = 0
            if self.display_blue[n] < 0:
                self.display_blue[n] = 0
            if self.display_alpha[n] < 0:
                self.display_alpha[n] = 0

            print("LOCATION: %d | SECTION:     r:%d    g:%g    b:%d     a:%d      | DISPLAY:     r:%d    g:%g    b:%d     a:%d" % (n,self.bg_red[n],self.bg_green[n],self.bg_blue[n],self.bg_alpha[n],self.display_red[n],self.display_green[n],self.display_blue[n],self.display_alpha[n]))

            color = QColor(self.display_red[n], self.display_green[n], self.display_blue[n])
            color.setAlpha(self.display_alpha[n])
            cursor = self.textCursor()
            cursor.setPosition(n)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, 1)
            charfmt = cursor.charFormat()
            charfmt.setBackground(color)
            self.setCurrentCharFormat(charfmt)
            self.setTextCursor(cursor)


    def color_sections(self):
        for n in range(self.sections.id.count()):
            print("-----SECTION:%d-----" % (n))
            section = self.sections.iloc[n]
            self.blend_colors(section.start, section.end, section.r, section.g, section.b, section.a)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create database and sections to highlight
    fn='qda_test_01.sqlite'
    db=connect_database(fn)
    id=create_data(db)
    db.close()

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QTextEdit2(
        "In addition, the PySide.QtCore.QPoint class provides the PySide.QtCore.QPoint.manhattanLength() function which gives an inexpensive approximation of the length of the PySide.QtCore.QPoint object interpreted as a vector. Finally, PySide.QtCore.QPoint objects can be streamed as well as compared.")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the application for this? What exactly is the purpose of the highlighting? Your code is very hard to understand without any context.

Comment: My code is also hard to understand because I am new to Python and rusty at programming in general. Each highlight represents a category assigned by one or more researchers. Researchers will re-categorize and even delete highlights, which often overlap several layers deep. Users can change colors as they prefer. In the social sciences, this process is called "[coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_(social_sciences))" interviews. I suspect that my problem is in the setPosition, movePosition, set format lines. But, if the code is too unreadable, I can try a more basic example and re-post.

Comment: The code seems to work OK when there is only one highlight. So, something goes awry when the process it repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had used the code I gave you in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634111/984421), the current example would work correctly. As it is, your changes have introduced lots of off-by-one errors.

To debug this, you should have first checked to see exactly which blocks of text should be highlighted. Taking the first 65 characters of the text and the start/end values from the database, this gives:

```
>>> t = "In addition, the PySide.QtCore.QPoint class provides the PySide."
>>> t[0:20]
'In addition, the PyS'
>>> t[15:20]
'e PyS'
>>> t[18:30]
'ySide.QtCore'
>>> t[50:60]
'es the PyS'
```

If you compare this to the highlights in the actual output, you'll see that none of the sections match up correctly (e.g. look at "S" in each "PySide").

To get this to work properly, you must get the text-cursor **once** at the beginning, use that to make all the necessary changes, and then re-set it **once** at the end:

```
cursor = self.textCursor()
for n in range(start, end):
    ...
    cursor.setPosition(n)
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
    charfmt = cursor.charFormat()
    charfmt.setBackground(color)
    cursor.setCharFormat(charfmt)
cursor.clearSelection()
self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

This is analogous to updating a database: you use a cursor to schedule a series of changes, and then commit them as a single operation at the end.

Comment: Your code corrects the issue and your explanation is very helpful, especially pointing out that setTextCursor is analogous to a database commit. Given that the context is a text editing widget, I expected the "cursor" to behave identically to the cursor in a word processor, with cursor.setCharFormat instantly having an effect. As I tried to get my code to work, I ventured further and further from your previous code.